# I'm modeling in 3ds max, but the scale is strange

Tags: unity-game-engine, scale, 3dsmax

Reset XForm is applied, and when Imported to Unity
scale has changed
For example, if you exported with a size of 10 10 10
There is a bug in Unity that imports in the size of 15 15 15.

How can i fix this bug?
And can you tell me what causes this bug?
Due to this issue, scale within Unity is constantly
You have to do it by hand.
I hope you can resolve this question as soon as possible.
I tried searching through google, but couldn't find the problem.

Comment: Is the Unity scale all ones or something different? Have you checked the export units? Unity is meters.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Check your units configuration in 3ds Max. Max will internally use its own "universal" units, but present different values in the UI depending on what units are configured. When you export, the universal units are used.